# Trigger updating child with parent value when a field on the parent is changed

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

I attempted to write an apex trigger but kept failing. I need to update three fields on the contact when one of two fields is changed on the parent account. One field needs to be updated with today's date(TODAY()) while the other fields need to be updated with the value of the parent fields. Here is what I have so far.

Edited Code:

```
trigger UpdateContacts on Acoount (after update){
   Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
       List<Contact> ContactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
           for (Account account: Trigger.new) {
                   Account oldaccount = Trigger.oldMap.get(Account.Id);
                           if (
                                       Account.Beginning_Balance__c != oldaccount.Beginning_Balance__c ||
                                       Account.Ending_Balance__c != oldaccount.Ending_Balance__c        ) {

                                 accountIds.add(account.Id);        }    }
                                     for (Contact contact: [
                                             select Ending_Balance_Date__c,Beginning_Date__c,Today_s_Date__c, 
                                                        Account_Name__c       
                                                         from Contact      
                                                          where Account_Name__c in :accountIds    ]) {
                                                                      contact.Today_s_Date__c = Today();            
                                                                      contact.Ending_Balance_Date__c = Trigger.newMap.get(contact.Account_Name__c).Ending_Balance__c;            
                                                                      contact.Beginning_Date__c = Trigger.newMap.get(contact.Account_Name__c).Beginning_Balance__c;
            ContactsToUpdate.add(Contact);    }
                if (!ContactsToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
                        update ContactsToUpdate;    }
                        }
```

Any help you could provide me with would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed 2 things in your code:

1- You are using Contacts instead of Contact in the SOQL.

2- You have not specified how it is failing. Is it runtime error or compilation error. According to the code snippet you have provided this code will have a compilation error at these 2 lines:

```
contacts.Ending_Balance_Date__c = account.Ending_Balance__c;            

contacts.Beginning_Date__c = account.Beginning_Balance__c;
```

account variable is no longer accessible as it is out of the scope where it has initialized (The for-loop). You need to get the value from

```
contacts.Ending_Balance_Date__c = Trigger.newMap.get(contacts.AccountId).Ending_Balance__c;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I made your suggested changes but am getting this error "Error: Compile Error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void get(Schema.SObjectField) from the type Map<Id,Account> at line 5 column 70."

Comment: I edited my question to include the new code snippet.

Comment: In line 5 you are referring to sObject Account not the account variable. It should be as the following:


    Account oldaccount = Trigger.oldMap.get(account.Id);